# jQuery won't execute, even with .noConflict();

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I've googled this extensively and still can't debug the issue - I'm setting `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`, I've verified that the js and css files are loading properly on the page. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? I'm also using bootstrap but it's working fine and I assume that wouldn't cause a conflict. Following [this](http://www.tehnrd.com/setting-up-jquery-with-salesforce-com/) example.

Includes:

```
<link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI, 'jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css')}" rel="stylesheet" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI, 'jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI, 'jquery-ui-1.11.4/external/jquery/jquery.js')}"/>
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

  j$(document).ready(function(){
        j$("#ninjaLink").click(function() {
            alert("NINJA STAR TO FACE!!!!!");
        });
    });


</script>

<a id="ninjaLink" href="">NINJA ATTACK!</a>
```

Just to verify the files are loading, this is right from the page (both jquery.js and jquery-ui.min.js are loaded, as well as the css):
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is that you have created a variable `$j` but you have used `j$` in the script to access DOM elements. Just change the variable name to `j$` and that should start working.

Comment: doh! this is exactly right. was tearing my hair out over this, it works now. i'll accept in 10 mins ;)

Comment: Here is a way to stick to using $ for jQuery without impacting any other definitions of $ https://force201.wordpress.com/2015/04/18/adding-javascript-and-jquery-to-visualforce-pages/.